# Euler-Lagrange $f(y,y',x) = \sqrt{1+y'^2}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I don't understand few steps in my book for an example.

Firstly, I have this $$f(y,y',x) = \sqrt{1+y'^2}$$

Euler-Lagrange equation  $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}=0$$

Then, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$ which means $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}$ is a constant.

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} = \frac{y'}{(1+y'^2)^{1/2}}$$

I know $$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} = 0$$

However, I don't know how I can get $y'^2 = C^2(1+y'^2)$

Comment: Look for the energy function (Hamilton function)  conserved along the solutions of the Euler-Lagrange equations....

Comment: Alternatively, write the conservation equation you found calling $C$ the constant value...

Comment: I have not seen the Hamilton function yet. I thought it was only a mathematical problem. I mean integrate.

Comment: Ok, use the second suggestion.

Comment: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} =C$ is the equation you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! is there a reason we have both sides squared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you state in the question, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$ and so it follows that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^\prime}$ is a constant. Let's give a suggestive name to this constant and call it $C$. Then we have
$$
\frac{y^\prime}{(1+y^{\prime\,2})^{1/2}}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^\prime}=C.
$$
Squaring both sides of this equality,
$$
\frac{y^{\prime\,2}}{1+y^{\prime\,2}}=C^2.
$$
Finally, multiply the denominator to the right hand side. This is the desired result.

Comment: Thanks! I never see this kind of thing. One more thing. is there a reason why we have both sides squared.

Comment: I'm afraid you would have to ask the person who wrote the question why they wanted it squared. Could be something as simple as "looks nicer," or they may have just descided to stop half-way to solving for $y^\prime$. You'll note that by moving the $y^\prime$ on the right over to the left, it's straightforward to solve for $y^\prime$ (move some constants around and take a square root). This would be the necessary next step to finding $y(x)$ (hint, you will get a straight line, which is the minimal distance between two points).

Comment: Alright, thanks alots